# How to find the derivative of $e^r(1-\frac{2P}K)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the derivative of $$R'(P)= e^r(1-\frac{2P}K)$$

Here $r$ and $K$ are constants.

I need to solve for this using the product rule. I know that $f(P)= e^r$, $f'(P)= e^r$, $g(P)= 1-\frac{2P}K$, $g'(P)= -\frac 2K$.
i am not sure if $g'(P)$ is correct

Comment: What is $r$?  Is it a variable, a function of $p$, or a constant?

Comment: You shouldn't use the notation $f(x)$ if you don't have $x$ as the independent variable. I'm not sure if it is $f(r)$ or $f(P)$ or $f(r,P)$ though

Comment: What is the independent variable here? If it's $p$, then your "$g'(x)$" is correct (although it should be denoted $g'(p)$), but your "$f'(x)$" isn't. Since there's no $x$ in the given expression at all, nothing else could possibly be "of $x$".

Comment: f(p) and g(p) and this function is R'(P)

Comment: it says to find the first and second derivative for R with P>0

Comment: So is $r$ supposed to be a constant?

Comment: If $p$ (or $P$?) is the independent variable, then you don't need the Product Rule at all.

Comment: the first derivative is e^r(1-2P/K)

Comment: yes r is constant

Comment: OK, then I'm editing that into your question.  Make sure it's still correct.

Comment: okay thank you! sorry for the confusion

Comment: Well, I'm surprised nobody has answered. So here it is: if $r$ is constant then $e^r$ is also constant.  So you don't need the product rule -- the only variable in this is the $P$. Basically the form is just $y = mx+b$ so when you take the derivative you just get the constant factors in front of $P$.  That is $R''(P) =-\dfrac{2e^r}{K}$.

Comment: Ok thank you! this helped alot!